# How to simplify angular library compilation

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, compilation

I have built an angular(ng6) library, the library work but i found there are several folder in my library: bundle, esm5, esm2015, fesm5 and fesm2015, they all have the different compilation of my library.

I can guess they are built to work in different ECMAScript environment.

But what if I only want to support one version of es, for example es2015, can i remove esm5 and fesm5 folder?

If i can, how should i config my tsconfig and ng-package.json to simplify the compilation. If i can't, why?

In additional, what is the difference between esm and fesm, i found in website it only use the file in fesm2015, the file structure are different that in fesm the code is compiled in one js file and in esm it complied in separate files.

Comment: did you manage to get an answer for this?

Comment: @OamPsy, i found although when you use npm to install the package you will install all of these js files, but when you build your application the tree shake will remove those code you have never used, so there is no need to worry about this problem.